# Antlr4 target C# error

Tags: c#, antlr4

I have setup my C# project to use the Antlr4 build targets and extension for compiling the g4 grammer.  However, when I build I am getting the following errors.  Any thoughts?

```
Error   1   The name 'HIDDEN' does not exist in the current context C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   131 22  oracle
Error   2   The name 'HIDDEN' does not exist in the current context C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   136 22  oracle
Error   4   The name 'HIDDEN' does not exist in the current context C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   145 22  oracle
Error   5   'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' does not contain a definition for 'LA' and no extension method 'LA' accepting a first argument of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   156 25  oracle
Error   6   'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' does not contain a definition for 'LA' and no extension method 'LA' accepting a first argument of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   156 44  oracle
Error   7   'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' does not contain a definition for 'LA' and no extension method 'LA' accepting a first argument of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   156 64  oracle
Error   8   'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' does not contain a definition for 'LA' and no extension method 'LA' accepting a first argument of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.ICharStream' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Lexer.cs   156 84  oracle
Error   9   The name 'EOF' does not exist in the current context    C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Parser.cs  920 23  oracle
Error   10  'oracle.Verilog2001Parser' does not contain a definition for 'EOF'  C:\gNOSIS\Oracle\Software\oracle\oracle\obj\x64\Debug\Verilog2001Parser.cs  875 66  oracle
```

Comment: What have you got so far? No idea at all, how do you interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, along with a few other related issues, was fixed in the following recent series of commits:

https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/compare/2ac3c964...c0aa59cb

These changes will be included in the next release. Until then you can use the following in your lexer grammar (for combined grammars use `@lexer::members`):

```
@members {
    public const int EOF = Eof;
    public const int HIDDEN = Hidden;
}
```

---

Errors 5-8 are related to semantic predicates in your grammar. In the C# target, the lookahead method is `La`, not `LA`.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, I am new to Antlr.  Do I add the @members{} statement to the Verilog2001.g4 grammer file to correct the problem then?  Thanks.

Comment: Since that would be a combined grammar (containing parser and lexer rules in the same file), you'd need to use the @lexer::members{} syntax, but yes, that's the file I'm referring to.

Answer (score -1):

For the "La" / "LA" part you can add some extension methods to fix it:

```
namespace Antlr4.Runtime
{
    public static class AntlrCsCompatability
    {
        public static int LA(this ICharStream self, int i)
        {
            return self.La(i: i);
        }
    }
}
```

Same holds true for the Lexer:

```
namespace GeneratedCode.ANTLR4
{
    public partial class STLexer
    {
        public const int EOF = Eof;
        public const int HIDDEN = Hidden;
    }

}
```